# search array for string

Tags: c, cstring

How would i implement this?Im trying to compare a array of c strings to a single string and if there is no match append it to the 2d array.

```
char*mprt,uni[100][16];
    mprt = &uni[0][0];
for (int s = 0;s <= 99;s++)
        {
            for (int z = 0;z <= 15;z++)
            {
                if (strcmp(mprt++, string1) != 0)
                {
                    uni[s][z] = string1[z];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When the strings are equal, the return value of strcmp is zero.

Comment: yes i know that, im checking to see if there is no match, if there isnt add the string to the array

Comment: Is this homework? If so, that's fine, but it should have the `homework` tag

Comment: Your question kinda doesn't make sense the way you're asking it. You can't "append" to the list; it's a fixed size. If you mean the array isn't full at the start, you have to keep track of how many words are in it. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: maybe i used the wrong wording. uni[100][16] is initially empty, string 1 is not, i want it scan the array for a match and if there is no match in uni add the string to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok ... from your comments I now get what you're trying to do. You'd want to make this into a function so you could feed words to it, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Note that you can use `char[][]`, but this way your strings can be of any length because we dynamically allocate them when we put them in the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    /* space for 100 strings */
    char **uni = calloc(100, sizeof(char*));
    char **i;

    /* Put one word in the list for test */
    *uni = calloc(5, sizeof(char*));
    strncpy(*uni, "this", 5);

    /* here's the string we're going to search for */
    char * str2 = "that";

    /* go through the first dimension looking for the string 
       note we have to check that we don't exceed our list size */
    for (i = uni; *i != NULL && i < uni+100; i++)
    {
        /* if we find it, break */
        if (strcmp(*i,str2) == 0)
            break;
    }

    /* if we didn't find the string, *i will be null 
     * or we will have hit the end of our first dimension */
   if (i == uni  + 100)
   {
        printf("No more space!\n");
   }        
   else if (*i == NULL)
   {
        /* allocate space for our string */
        *i = calloc(strlen(str2) + 1, sizeof(char));

        /* copy our new string into the list */
        strncpy(*i, str2, strlen(str2) + 1);
    }


    /* output to confirm it worked */
    for (i = uni; *i != NULL && i < uni+100; i++)
        printf("%s\n",*i);
}
```

For completeness, the `char[][]` version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    char uni[100][16];
    int i,j;

    /* init our arrays */
    for (i=0;i<100;i++)
        for (j=0;j<16;j++)
            uni[i][j] = '\0';


    /* Put one word in the list for test */
    strncpy(uni[0], "this",15);

    /* here's the string we're going to search for */
    char * str2 = "that";

    /* go through the first dimension looking for the string */
    for (i = 0; uni[i][0] != '\0'  && i < 100; i++)
    {
        /* if we find it, break */
        if (strcmp(uni[i],str2) == 0)
            break;
    }

    /* if we didn't find the string, uni[i][0] will be '\0'
     * or we will have hit the end of our first dimension */
    if (i == 100)
    {
        printf("No more space!\n");
    }
    else if (uni[i][0] == '\0')
    {
        /* copy our new string into the array */
        strncpy(uni[i], str2, 15);
    }

    /* output to confirm it worked */
    for (i = 0; uni[i][0] != '\0' && i < 100; i++)
        printf("%s\n",uni[i]);
}
```

**Edit to explain C pointers and arrays from comments below:**

In C, arrays degrade to pointers. This is actually really confusing when you first start.

If I have `char myArray[10]` and I want to pass that to a function that takes a `char *` argument, I can use either `&myArray[0]` or just `myArray`. When you leave off the index, it degrades to a pointer to the first element in the array.

In a multidimensional array like yours, `&uni[5][0]` == `uni[5]` - both are pointers to the first element in the second dimension at index 5 in the first. It degrades to `char*` pointed at the beginning of the 6th word in your list.

Comment: thanks for typing that all out, ill see what i can take from it,some of its a bit advanced for me

Comment: I'm adding the char[][] ... one sec.

Comment: oh i see bit easier for me to understand

Comment: FYI = `strncpy()` is a safe version of `strcpy()` - the third argument limits the number of characters it will copy so that you can't overflow a buffer.

Comment: thanks Brian ,your  second version was much easier for me to understand, i get it now

Comment: one question , in your second for loop its only searching through the rows and not the collums?

Comment: What you have to understand is that in C, arrays degrade to pointers. So if you have `char c[10]`, using just `c` is the same as `&c[0]`; it's a pointer to the first element in the array. With your multidementional array, using `uni[0]` means you have a pointer to the first element in the second dimension; `uni[0] == &uni[0][0]` this is why you can pass it to string functions as a `char *` - you'll note that `strcpy()` and `strcmp()` both take `char *` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, you need to copy the whole string to append it,

Replace the line by this,

```
strcpy(uni[s], string1[z]);
```

Considering `string1[z]` is an element of an array of char pointers.

**Edit:**

Not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but you'll end up with all elements set to `string1`

```
char string1[] = "String";

char uni[100][16] = {};

for (int s = 0; s < 100; s++)
{
    if (strcmp(uni[s], string1) != 0)
    {
        strcpy(uni[s], string1);
    }
}
```

---

Or this, without `strcpy()`

```
char string1[] = "String";

char uni[100][16] = {};

for (int s = 0; s < 100; s++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < sizeof(string1); r++)
    {
        uni[s][r] = string1[r];
    }
}
```

Comment: string1 is declared as this char string1[16];

Comment: @Bob: you need to make sure that the string is null-terminated '\0' before you copy it.

Comment: invalid conversion from `char' to `const char*'

Comment: @Bob: In case of `char string1[16]`, `string1` is your pointer to string, `string1[16]` is an array of chars.

Comment: @Bob: Exactly, and you don't need the nested for loop.

Comment: why would you index uni like a normal array when its a 2d array?

Answer (score 0):

to append to the end of the 2D array you need to use dynamic memory allocation

```
    const int row_max = 100, col_max = 16;
char** uni = NULL;
char searchString[col_max] = "xyz";
int currentLength = 0;

uni = (char**) malloc (row_max * sizeof(char*)); //TODO:error handling code to be added
for (int row = 0; row < row_max; row++)
{
    uni[row]    = (char*)malloc(col_max * sizeof(char));//TODO:error handling code to be added 
    currentLength = row;
}

for (int row = 0; row < row_max; row++) //fill array uni with data here
{
    uni[row] = "abc";
}

for (int row = 0; row < row_max; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < col_max; col++)
    {
        if (strcmp(&uni[row][col], searchString) != 0 ) 
        {//string not found

            uni = (char**)realloc(uni, (currentLength + 1) * sizeof(char*));//TODO:error handling code to be added 
            uni[currentLength + 1] = (char*)malloc(col_max);//TODO:error handling code to be added 
            currentLength++;
            strcpy(uni[currentLength],searchString); //append at end of 2D array 
            goto stop;
        }
    }
}
```

stop:
    for (int row = 0; row <= currentLength; row++)
        free(uni[row]);
    free(uni);

```
return 0;
```