# C function like in_array in PHP

Tags: php, c

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

Is there some function in C which does similar thing to `in_array` in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466432/search-array-for-string

Comment: Nope, you have to implement it yourself :) btw, `in_array()` is case sensitive, so `in_array('mac', $s)` will be `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nope**, but you can  implement like this

```
typedef int (*cmpfunc)(void *, void *);

int in_array(void *array[], int size, void *lookfor, cmpfunc cmp)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (cmp(lookfor, array[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char *str[] = {"this is test", "a", "b", "c", "d"};

    if (in_array(str, 5, "c", strcmp))
        printf("yes\n");
    else
        printf("no\n");

    return 0;
}
```